# Generic where condition in Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm building an application which uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 to query data from database.

I've used this function:

```
private IQueryable<T> SearchPropertyText(IQueryable<T> records, Func<T, string> property, TextSearch search)
{
    switch (search.Mode)
    {
        case TextSearchMode.ContainIgnoreCase:
            records = records.Where(x => property(x).Contains(search.Text));
            break;
        case TextSearchMode.Equal:
            records = records.Where(x => property(x).Equals(search.Text));
            break;
        case TextSearchMode.EqualIgnoreCase:
            records = records.Where(x => property(x).Equals(search.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            break;
        default:
            records = records.Where(x => property(x).Contains(search.Text));
            break;
    }
    return records;
}
```

This function is for helping me filter text properties by passing property name and text search. For example:

```
users = SearchPropertyText(users, user => user.Email, emailSearch);
```

This function is running fine on Entity Framework Core 1.1.1 . But when I copy this code to Entity Framework 6.1.3. It gave me an exception :

**The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm sure. Because I'm using this function in my .net core project. It runs smoothly.

Comment: Real database. My database is deployed on Azure. The function works with EF Core, not EF 6.1.3

Comment: No. I just used : db.Records.AsQueryable() , without ToList

Comment: I removed AsQueryable. But the function doesn't work.

Comment: Can anyone help me, please ?